# ObjC using a variable in a block that fires in another class

Tags: objective-c, variables, block

I am using Facebook SDK 3 which uses Blocks as CompletionHandlers.
I want to use a local scope variable (Argument) in the passing block to FBRequestConnection

```
-(void)     shareStoryWithHandle:(const int)HID parameters:(NSString*)jsonparams
{
    if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
    {
         FBRequestHandler my_handler = ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
        {
            // do somthing with HID
            // but HID is 0 in this scope while is correct in shareStoryWithHandle scope!
        }
        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
                                 parameters:[jsonparams objectFromJSONString]
                                 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                          completionHandler:my_handler];
    }
}
```

How can i use HID in the Block scope, and i cant store it in the class!

Answer (score 0):

Your assertion that `HID` is 0 in the block is wrong. When you create the block it takes a const copy of any captured variables, so if you reference `HID` in the block then the variable in the block will have the value that `HID` did at the point where the block was created.

Comment: i dont know how could i assert it wrong!
NSLog(@"HID:%d", HID); // return 1 in shareStoryWithHandle scope

NSLog(@"HID:%d", HID); // return 0 in block scope

Comment: Acutely @Kevin Ballard was write,
Both values are 0!
the problem was completely from somewhere else, I'm such an inobservant...